# JQuery - Split String (For Each)

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, foreach, split

Current Code Below - I have to copy and paste each `arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]`. However, in the future I may have more or less array options and would like the code to auto update itself without needing to alter my code.

Basically, I want to create a "for-each" situation for each list item:

```
<li><i class='icon-check twentytwo color'></i><span>" + arr + "</span></li>
```

Current Code:

```
var data = $('.availability').text();
var arr = data.split('•');
$('.availability').html("<li><i class='icon-check twentytwo color'></i><span>" + arr[0] + "</span></li><li><i class='icon-check twentytwo color'></i><span>" + arr[1] + "</span></li><li><i class='icon-check twentytwo color'></i><span>" + arr[2] + "</span></li>");
```

---

**ANSWER** = All of these would have worked in various situations. I selected my answer based on the fact that I am using a handlebar template making some of these code snippets not usable for my project.

Comment: I am having to copy and paste `<li><i class='icon-check twentytwo color'></i><span>" + arr[#] + "</span></li>` into the code for each array. I may want more than the three I have now in the future and want the code to know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** for that

```js
var data = $('.availability').text();
var arr = data.split('•');
$('.availability').html("<li><i class='icon-check twentytwo color'></i><span>" 
                        + arr.join("</span></li><li><i class='icon-check twentytwo color'></i><span>") 
                        + "</span></li>");
```

Answer (score 8):

You can loop your array by using the [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function.

But instead of using `html()` which will override your HTML, you should `append()` the items.

```
var data = $('.availability').text();
var arr = data.split('•');
$.each( arr, function( index, value ) {
    $('.availability').append("<li><i class='icon-check twentytwo color'></i><span>" + value + "</span></li>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 var data = $('.availability').text();
    var arr = data.split('•');
    for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
     $('.availability').append("<li><i class='icon-check twentytwo color'></i><span>" + arr[i] + "</span></li>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```js
var data = $('.availability').text();
var arr = data.split('•');
var htm;
$.each(arr, function(i, obj){
   htm += $('<li>', {
       html:"<i class='icon-check twentytwo color'></i><span>"+ arr[i] + "</span>"
   })
})

$('.availability').html(htm);
```